# Getting country from Geolocation IP (React Remix)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, geolocation, server-side-rendering, remix

I'm facing a challenge in my Remix app. I have a server-side file responsible for processing client requests and returning their country. I'm looking for guidance on the best practices to optimize both performance and code quality for this task.

Additionally, I'm encountering an issue when requiring these modules:

```
const requestIp = require('request-ip');
const geoip = require('fast-geoip');
```

I'm wondering if it would be advisable to create a dedicated route, such as "routes/country.ts," to handle this logic. Alternatively, should I include it in "server.ts" or "entry.server.ts"? My main concern is to avoid loading the entire geoip database into memory multiple times.

In my "root.tsx" file, which processes the initial request and determines the language for displaying content, I have the following code snippet:

```
export async function loader({ context, request }: LoaderArgs) {
  const { cart, session, storefront, sanity, env, i18n } = context;

  const country = await requestCountry(request);
  console.log({ country });

  // ... rest of the code
}
```

For retrieving the country from the request, I'm using the following component:

```
const requestIp = require('request-ip');
const geoip = require('fast-geoip');

const pickHeader = (name) => ({ headers = {} }) => headers[name];

const providers = [
  pickHeader('cf-ipcountry'), // Cloudflare
  pickHeader('x-vercel-ip-country'), // Vercel
  pickHeader('x-appengine-country'), // Google App Engine
];

const fromProvider = (req) => {
  let provider;
  providers.find((fromProvider) => (provider = fromProvider(req)));
  return provider;
};

const fromIpAddress = async (req) => {
  const ipAddress = req.ipAddress || req.ip || requestIp.getClientIp(req);

  if (ipAddress) {
    const geo = await geoip.lookup(ipAddress);
    if (geo) return geo.country;
  }
};

module.exports = async (req = {}) =>
  fromProvider(req) || (await fromIpAddress(req)) || null;
```

Hope anyone can help! Thank you